# Can't get the text of the JQuery dialog to display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have newly discovered the JQueryUI dialog.  But it doesn't display properly. I have a div designated dialog-confirm.  The dialog is being set with a yes and no button.  It has a title.

The dialog is displayed when there is a particular response back from an AJAX Call.  So that the dialog is declare like this:

```
 if (data.result.Data.HasAssociatedGFM) {
     var GFMvalue = data.result.Data.HasAssociatedGFM;
     $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
          //height: 500,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                  "Yes": function () {
                         $("#HasGFM").val(GFMvalue);
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                  },
                  "No": function () {
                         $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              }
      });
  }
```

The dialog div looks like this:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Has GFM?" style="display:none;text-align:center;
position: fixed;height:15%; width: 50%;top: 35%;left: 25%;/*margin-left: -190px;
margin-top: -100px;*/background-color: #ffffff;border: 2px solid #336699;padding: 0px;
z-index: 102;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12pt; ">
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">
         </span>
          Is this a GFM End Item requirement?
      </p>
</div>
```

The display of the div is set to none because it will otherwise show upon page load.  When the dialog function is called when the AJAX call returns the proper value, then the dialog opens; it shows the title, and the buttons; it carries out the function of the buttons; but there is no text for the user explaining it.  I tried changing the height of the div, and changing the height of the dialog.  Doing the former makes no difference; doing the latter narrows the width of the dialog without increasing the height or altering the parameters of the div.

I went to the JqueryUI tutorial site found about all the available options but that did not help.  I viewed many of the stackoverflow posts as well but none of the resolutions there made a difference.

Comment: This div did not paste properly.  Actually it looks like this: <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Has GFM?" style="display:none;text-align:center;position: fixed;height:15%; width: 50%;top: 35%;left: 25%;/*margin-left: -190px;margin-top: -100px;*/background-color: #ffffff;border: 2px solid #336699;padding: 0px;z-index: 102;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12pt; ">

          <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
              Is this a GFM End Item requirement?</p>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `autoOpen: false`, you will need to call [open()](https://jsfiddle.net/0yvhvL1m/6/) in order to show your dialog.  But more importantly, your inline css is overriding the dialog css and causing it to not work correctly.  You also have your dialog init inside your condition, but it should be at global scope.

1. Remove your inline css.
2. Move the initialization of your dialog outside the IF condition so it has global scope.
3. Inside your IF condition, call open() to open your dialog
4. It looks like you're trying to add some value from your JSON response to the modal, but the id you're referencing does not exist in your HTML.  You can easily add that element to your div, and then insert the value just before you call open();

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Has GFM?">Is this a GFM End Item requirement?<span id="HasGFM"></span></div>
```

**JQuery** (add GFMvalue to span and open the dialog)

```
$("#HasGFM").text("47");
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0yvhvL1m/6/).  Note:  Instead of using a condition to display the dialog, I'm using a button click.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained at 
http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28906222/Can't-get-the-text-of-the-JQuery-dialog-to-display.html

the above solution will not work.

Instead I removed all of the inline style from the div except "Display:None", and left everything else the same.  Now it works as desired.